# present modal view hides the navigation bar in navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have spent hours on this wired problem.

The scenario is I have push a new chatting view controller to the root navigation controller.

Then I customized the navigation bar item in the viewdidload method.

Everything works fine.

Then I present a image picker view which enables the image upload function.

And dismiss that picker view, which was presented as modal view.

After the picker view dismissed, the customized  left navigation bar button disappeared.

The navigation bar appearance is the same as the root navigation bar but not the customized appearance is the current view controller.

Because the some pieces of the work includes the third party SDK, so I am not able to directly change the UIPickerView in order to detect the dismiss event and change the navigation bar appearance.

Can anyone helps? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you present `UIImagePicker` with `UINavigationBarController`?

Answer (score 0):

You should removed  customised the navigation bar item on viewWillDisappear and add this viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: I have added a break point in the viewWillAppear method. After the modal view dismissed, the viewWillAppear in the current view controller is not called, but the viewWillAppear in the root view controller in was reached.

Comment: Please confirm have you added [super viewWillAppear:animated];  in viewWillAppear method ?

Comment: Yes, I have add the [super viewWillAppear:animated], the method was called once the view controller is just pushed. But only viewWillAppear in the root view controller is called after the modal view is dismissed